# How to default `:global` in css-modules in next-js?

Tags: webpack, next.js, css-modules, css-loader

I am using CSS modules in a Next.js project. Suppose I have some code like this:

```
// foo.module.(s)css

.foo :global {
   animation-name: bounce;
   // ...
}
```

Can I modify Webpack config in Next.js so that I don't need to specify `:global` at each selector, so that the value of `animation-name` is not hashed? In this case, I want `foo` to be hashed, but not `bounce`.

All my keyframes are defined in global stylesheet file. I don't want to scope keyframes cause I am using them multiple times, and scoping in that case is generating duplicate keyframes (just having different names).

Any help or suggestion for a better approach is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem in Next 13.

Comment: @nordic70 Nope. You can manually specify that `:global` thing, or better use utility classes approach (define classes in global stylesheet for each animation).

Answer (score 0):

My selected solution was to use CSS modules with `:global` operator to prevent hashed names. This enabled to use the names inside HTML managed by Lexical RTE.

Imported `styles.module` becomes the className for a wrapper. Afterwards the CSS class selectors can be referenced in the HTML.

```
/* Editor styles mapped to the class names in the HTML. */
.module :global .bold {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.module :global .underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.module :global .italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```